Workflow fails with exit code 127 - Action: command not found
I'm encountering an issue with my GitHub Actions workflow. The workflow is supposed to send a message to a Telegram channel when certain GitHub events occur. However, I'm getting an exit code 127 error, which indicates that a command is not found.
Here's a simplified version of my workflow:
name: Telegram Message

on:
  push:
  pull_request:
  issues:
  release:
  create:
  delete:
  fork:
  watch:
  deployment:
  deployment_status:
  milestone:
  repository_dispatch:

jobs:
  notify:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Send Message to Telegram
        run: |
          EVENT_NAME=${{ github.event_name }}
          REPO_NAME=${{ github.repository }}
          REPO_URL="https://github.com/${{ github.repository }}"
          BRANCH_NAME=${{ github.ref_name }}
          COMMIT_MESSAGE=${{ github.event.head_commit.message || 'N/A' }}
          COMMIT_AUTHOR=${{ github.event.head_commit.author.name || 'N/A' }}
          PR_TITLE=${{ github.event.pull_request.title || 'N/A' }}
          ISSUE_TITLE=${{ github.event.issue.title || 'N/A' }}
          RELEASE_NAME=${{ github.event.release.name || 'N/A' }}
          RELEASE_BODY=${{ github.event.release.body || 'N/A' }}
          FORK_NAME=${{ github.event.forkee.full_name || 'N/A' }}
          WATCHER=${{ github.actor || 'N/A' }}
          DEPLOYMENT_URL=${{ github.event.deployment.url || 'N/A' }}
          DEPLOYMENT_STATUS=${{ github.event.deployment_status.state || 'N/A' }}
          MILESTONE_TITLE=${{ github.event.milestone.title || 'N/A' }}
          DISPATCH_EVENT_TYPE=${{ github.event.action || 'N/A' }}

          MESSAGE="**Event Type:** $EVENT_NAME\n"
          MESSAGE+="**Repository:** $REPO_NAME\n"
          MESSAGE+="**Repository URL:** $REPO_URL\n"
          MESSAGE+="**Branch:** $BRANCH_NAME\n"

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "push" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Commit Message:** $COMMIT_MESSAGE\n"
            MESSAGE+="**Commit Author:** $COMMIT_AUTHOR\n"
          fi

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "pull_request" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Pull Request Title:** $PR_TITLE\n"

          fi

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "issues" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Issue Title:** $ISSUE_TITLE\n"

          fi

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "release" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Release Name:** $RELEASE_NAME\n"
            MESSAGE+="**Release Body:** $RELEASE_BODY\n"
          fi


          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "fork" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Forked Repository:** $FORK_NAME\n"
          fi

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "watch" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Watcher:** $WATCHER\n"
          fi

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "deployment" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Deployment URL:** $DEPLOYMENT_URL\n"
          fi

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "deployment_status" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Deployment Status:** $DEPLOYMENT_STATUS\n"
          fi


          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "milestone" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Milestone Title:** $MILESTONE_TITLE\n"
          fi

          if [ "$EVENT_NAME" == "repository_dispatch" ]; then
            MESSAGE+="**Dispatch Event Type:** $DISPATCH_EVENT_TYPE\n"
          fi

          curl -s -X POST "https://api.telegram.org/bot${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}/sendMessage" \
            -d chat_id=${{ secrets.CHAT_ID }} \
            -d text="$MESSAGE" \
            -d parse_mode=Markdown
        env:
          TELEGRAM_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.TELEGRAM_TOKEN }}
          TELEGRAM_CHAT_ID: ${{ secrets.CHAT_ID }}

Error Message:


Ensured that environment variables TELEGRAM_TOKEN and CHAT_ID are correctly set in GitHub Secrets.
Checked the syntax of my YAML file.

Seems like all those env vars inside run can be moved under env.

The commit message seems to have a leading space: “ Action …” you can fix the error like this
COMMIT_MESSAGE=$(echo ${{ github.event.head_commit.message || 'N/A' }})


Omg, thank you so much! That took me 3 hours

I am glad the issue is solved  If this is the case, please accept the answer. Thank you.
